# Jazz tones with PRS SE245

Tags: guitar, jazz

I am playing a solid body guitar, PRS SE245 and actually I want to have some jazz sounds.
I am combining this guitar with Blackstar LT Echo 10 and actually couldn't succeed to get the tones of jazz.

So I am considering changing pick ups but I am not sure if it will be the solution or can I have jazz sounds with my current set up?

Comment: There are thousands of jazz tones. You don’t need to change pickups on any guitar to get tones that sound good for jazz. What do you not like about the tone you currently have coming from the guitar?

Comment: I always thought "basic jazz sound" was "set tone pot to 2" ;)) but actually, looking at that guitar you also ought to get rid of the skinny 8s & put at least 10s on there, probably heavier. You can't do "jazz" with shredder strings.

Comment: Actually with jazz sound I try to refer more bass tones because right now it sounds a lot bright. Then as I understand I should change to some thicker strings did I get it right?

Comment: If you feel like your sound is too bright then lower the tone control(s) on the guitar and you can also lower the treble control on the amp and/or raise the middle and bass controls.

Comment: As John Belzaguy mentioned too unfortunately my amplifier doesn't have total control over tones but thank you I will keep it in mind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By “jazz tones” I assume you are talking about a dark mellow hollow body-ish sound ala Joe Pass, Wes Montgomery, etc. Your guitar isn’t really made for that sound but you can simulate it somewhat. I assume you want to have the pop/rock sound of the instrument available to you so based on that here are some suggestions:

- Use only the neck pickup
- Roll the tone knob down A LOT
- Try a compromise of heavier gauge strings that are comfortable enough for everything you want to play. Keep in mind that some jazz guitarists use up to 13’s (or higher) and sometimes flatwound strings too.
- It doesn’t look like your amp has much in the way of tone controls so get it as warm as you can.
- Consider some type of external eq if your tone control doesn’t roll off enough highs.

Comment: It was exactly what I was asking for! Thanks a lot.

Comment: A 7-band eq pedal (Boss, etc) would be a good move. And really old strings..!

Comment: @Tim Both good suggestions, If there are no old strings laying around you can always eat some fried chicken or barbecue right before practicing for a few days, lol! But seriously, the eq pedal is good, I have a Boss bass eq that can dial in and out a lot of specific tones.

Comment: Yes, it was based (!) on my bass eq. Also like the parametric eq. for a quick step on change of tone. And possibly use a thicker pick - or even a wooden one. Or one's thumb.

Comment: @Tim the thumb worked fairly well for Wes Montgomery!